# How to determine that the input is already filtered by CodeIgniter xss protection

Tags: codeigniter

global xss protection is set to TRUE now. but the poison input will be displayed as literally as [removed], so I need to know whether the input is poison or not, if it's poison I will drop it.

I can simply use the function strstr to do this, if there is [removed] in the string then it is poison.

but wouldn't it be better if CodeIgniter provided already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
word_censor();
```

a text helper

```
$disallowed = array('darn', 'shucks', 'golly', 'phooey');

$string = word_censor($string, $disallowed, 'Beep!');
```

Enables you to censor words within a text string. The first parameter will contain the original string. The second will contain an array of words which you disallow. The third (optional) parameter can contain a replacement value for the words. If not specified they are replaced with pound signs: ####. Example:

Comment: this is the only thing i found, it looks like there is not other option unfortunately

Comment: yes, I been trying to find something too. CI will filter anything from user's input given the global_xss_filtering is set to true, but it seems like CI can't tell whether it filtered a specific input or not. thank you pal

Comment: set the xss filtering to off, and use $this->input->post('name'); if it has some xss just redirect back, or you can use $this->input->post('name', true);

Comment: you can see the algoritm of checking xss in /system/core/security.php, look at the function xss_clean that is used by CI, and you can create other function that is checking for xss similar to xss_clean... and then using something like $this->security->check_xss($var); or creating a helper similar to that function